# Casting derived template class from virtual class

Tags: c++, templates, casting, abstract-class

In my code, I have one abstract class and ~8 child classes. I want to ask, is it possible in C++ to cast `typename` and return the calling class? I need something like separate `A<int>` as `A` and `int`. I need something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    T data;

    virtual void setData(T p_data) = 0;
    virtual ~Base();

    template<class TC<typename TV>>
    operator TC<TV>() const
    {
        TV tmp = (TV) data;
        return TC<TV>(tmp);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class A : public Base<T>
{
    A(T data)
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

    void setData(T p_data) override
    {
        data = p_data;
    }
};
```

I used to use D. In D, the next code solves this problem (I have included the D code below for a better understanding of what I want):

```
auto opCast(K, this R)() const
    {
        static if (is(R ClassType : Root!T, alias Root))
            K tmp = cast(K) data;
            return new Root!K(tmp);
        else
            throw new Exception("ClassType isn't equal (T)");
    }
```

Is there a solution for C++?

Comment: `template<class TC<typename TV>>` I'm not sure what you try to do here, I don't recognize this syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. FWIW, with a few tweaks the C++ code you posted will compile just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/z8hbK8v18

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It is the wrong syntax. Pseudocode. I think I have to send template type (from cast. `int` for example) and class name without template(`A` for example) to cast operator.

Comment: If all you are looking for a conditional cast from one type to another, then `dynamic_cast` is what you want.    It returns null when the cast is not valid.     And I think your incorrect syntax (in the thing that Guillaume was talkinga about) probably requires something called "template template" syntax

Comment: @WusikiJeronii I see. I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do. How do you intent to use the code? And from what type to what type you're trying to do the conversion?

Comment: @AndyG thanks. It is what I wanted. Sorry, for nub questions ;)

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? The point of having an abstract base class is that you don't need to know what the actual type is. So this makes me wonder what you are trying to achieve that makes you think you need the type.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot what done AndyG

Comment: @MartinYork why is it a strange question? Child classes in my code have different members and I want when I casting type return calling class. If I will return root class I can't get access to child class members 'cos these ones didn't define in the root class.

Comment: @WusikiJeronii `static if (is(R ClassType : Root!T, alias Root))` - that looks like something that can be accomplished in C++17 and later using [`Constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) with [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and/or [`std::is_base_of_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: @WusikiJeronii what you are asking for is unusual, and should not be needed if you were using polymorphism properly. That said, it would help if you would provide examples of how you expect to call the cast and use the result. But I'm with Joe on this, `dynamic_cast` is likely what you are looking for, then you don't need the converting operator at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think so. In D it means: if you can cast typename to ClassType where the structure is Root!T where Root is an alias of this (ClassType). And then Root is defined alias (typename). I think it is a unique D expression only, 'cos I know nothing about ClassType (as Object in JS) in C++ at least. But similar c++ code is there in the AndyG snippet.

Comment: It is still not clear what your end goal is. The problem here is that you think you need to do `A` so that you can eventually do `X`. The problem is you are asking about `A` and not in a very clear way. Maybe there is a better way of achieving `X` in C++ without doing `A`? It seems that `A` is not very C++ like and this is why you are having a hard time explaining it. So my question is really what is `X` can you show us what you are trying to achieve. An explicit example (without using abstract notation).

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you explain to me how to use dynamic_cast with templates. I tried but I get `NULL.` https://godbolt.org/z/Yz3j5nKTf

Comment: @WusikiJeronii I agree with Martin, this is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). You are focusing on the HOW of translating a particular operation from D to C++, instead of focusing on the WHY of what you are trying to accomplish with that operation. What is the GOAL here? For instance, `dynamic_cast` can be used to cast an object pointer/reference to another *compatible* type. So, if you have a `Base<T>*` pointer, you can directly cast it to a `Derived*` pointer if `Derived` inherits from `Base<T>`.

Comment: @WusikiJeronii in your example, `A<int>` and `A<float>` are **not related types**. Even though they use a common template `A`, they have different base types `Base<int>` and `Base<float>`, and thus you can't directly cast between them, at least not with `dynamic_cast`. Maybe with `reinterpret_cast` instead, but it is technically *undefined behavior* to cast between unrelated types, except for very specific exceptions (which this does not meet).

Comment: @RemyLebeau oooh. I've understood. Dynamic cast for class types. Simple cast for template types (`int`, `float`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your D code correctly, you are basically:

- taking the `ClassType` of the `this` object that is being converted,
- pattern-matching it to make sure it is a template with 1 argument, and then extracting the type of that template,
- casting the `this` object's `data` member to a specified input type,
- returning a new object of the template with the specified type as its argument.

There is nothing like `ClassType` in C++, so it is not possible for a base class to obtain the class type of a derived object, unless you use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to pass the derived type as a template parameter to the base class.

However, the `operator` you have is close to accepting any kind of template type for conversion, your syntax is just a little wrong. Try something more like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    T data;
    ...

    template<template<typename> typename TC, typename TV>
    operator TC<TV>() const
    {
        TV tmp = (TV) data;
        return TC<TV>(tmp);
    }
};
```

Then something like this would work:

```cpp
A<int> d(7);
A<float> e = d;
std::cout << e.data << std::endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fT5bGzes1)

The catch is that this `operator` will convert to *any* template that takes an argument that `data` can be converted to.  If you want to restrict the `operator` to only the same template that is being converted, you will need something more like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, template<typename> typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    T data;
    ...

    template<typename TV>
    operator Derived<TV>() const
    {
        return Derived<TV>(data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class A : public Base<T, A>
{
    typedef Base<T, A> my_base;

public:
    A(T p_data)
    {
        setData(p_data);
        std::cout << my_base::data << std::endl;
    }

    void setData(T p_data) override
    {
        my_base::data = p_data;
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3ocxP1Wqo)